# Why can't I automatically create a relationship using Graphileon?

Tags: cypher, graphileon

I am having trouble creating a relation in Graphileon.
To do so, it is indicated:

1. Select start node
2. Hold ctrl button on keybord
3. Select end node.
   This opens a relation form where you can edit it.

For me, this form is not created automatically. The only way to do so, is to create a cypher code and it is not practical at all.

Is there anyone who had this problem before !

Comment: Hi @Frikha, it is definitely possible to create edges without writing cypher! Not sure where things are going wrong. Which versions ( Graphileon and graph database ) are you using?

Comment: Hello, I am using Neo4j 4.4.3 and Graphileon 3.2.0

Comment: Ok.. did you try to hold ctrl down and drag a connection from source to target node?  if nothing works, please reach out to me on Slack : https://join.slack.com/t/graphileon-users/shared_invite/zt-fjrtq8wi-fdFNJWTBz1l5Xd7BseBclw

Comment: Thank you, I was doing it wrong. I didn't drag a connection between nodes, I was just clicking on them in addition to holding ctrl down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I was doing it wrong. I didn't drag a connection between nodes, I was just clicking on them in addition to holding ctrl down.